# Need help in improving the query

Tags: sql, select

I get an error

> "Invalid operation: table name "ball.songcollection" specified more than once;
>   1 statement failed."

do you know why this is? I'm new to SQL and trying to learn.

```
SELECT ball.songcollection.artist_name,
       ball.songcollection.songname,
       ball.performance.rank,
       ball.performance.genre

FROM   ball.songcollection, ball.performance
INNER JOIN ball.songcollection ON ball.songcollection.id=ball.performance.ball_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  And, learn to use table aliases:

```
SELECT sc.artist_name, sc.songname,
       p.rank, p.genre
FROM ball.performance p INNER JOIN
     ball.songcollection sc
     ON sc.id = p.ball_id;
```

You'll note that this removes the second reference to `songcollection`, which caused your syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

you are using two time the same table

```
    SELECT ball.songcollection.artist_name,
           ball.songcollection.songname,
           ball.perfob1rmance.rank,
           ball.performance.genre

    FROM   ball.songcollection 
    INNER JOIN  ball.performance  ON ball.songcollection.id=ball.performance.ball_id
```